# C code won't compile in mac Terminal.

Tags: c, macos, gcc, terminal

Whenever I run $ /developer/usr/bin/gcc -v main.c -o main in Terminal, I get the following error: stdio.h: No such file or directory.

Here is the main.c file

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i<10;i++){
        puts("Hello World!\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am pretty good with C, however I usually use xcode to compile any C command line programs. The same code runs fine in Xcode, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: It can't find the header file, you probably need to specify your SDK

Comment: How do I do that in terminal? I have located where the include folder where stdio.h is located on my computer, but I cant figure out how to get terminal to look there.

Comment: Looks like the isysroot option. From the clang manual: "For example, -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk will look for mylib.h in /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk/usr/include/mylib.h."

Comment: Ah that worked, thanks, how do I make it so that I do not have to type that every time?

Comment: Also, you can use `xcodebuild` from the command line, if it already builds from Xcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and fixed it. Just install xCode's command line tools and it'll all work just fine!

Hope it helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can install xcode tools with the command -

```
xcode-select --install
```

A fresh install of xcode command line tools will require 130MB of space and does require sudo access.